# File.Exists(path) devuelve resultado no esperado

Tags: c#, .net, consola, filesystem

Soy nueva trabajando con C# y necesito conocer si ciertos ficheros existen en un directorio, el cual se encuentra en la misma ubicación que la app. Para esto uso `File.Exists(path)`, pero en todos los casos me devuelve `false` mientras que las rutas de los ficheros analizados sí existen tal y como se consultan. 
Sin embargo primero compruebo si existe el directorio con `Directory.Exists("audiovisuales\\concierto\\")` para asegurarme de que estoy poniendo bien la ruta del directorio y obtengo `true`, por tanto no se que pasa que `File.Exists()` no me encuentra los ficheros.

Este es lo que hice:

```
...
using System.IO;

...

while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(0) + ";" + reader.GetValue(1) + ";" + reader.GetValue(2) + ";" + reader.GetValue(3));
    String codFilai = (String)reader.GetValue(0);// Ejemplo: codigoFilai = D001
    codFilai = codFilai.ToLower();//codigoFilai = d001, o v007, o c034

    if (codFilai.StartsWith("c"))
    {


        rutaVideo = "audiovisuales\\concierto\\"+codFilai+".flv'";
        rutaPortada = "audiovisuales\\concierto\\"+codFilai+".jpg'";
        Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(rutaVideo) ? "Video existe!" : "Video no existe.");
        Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(rutaPortada) ? "Portada existe!" : "Portada no existe.");
        Console.WriteLine(Directory.Exists("audiovisuales\\concierto\\") ? "Directorio existe!" : "Directorio no existe.");
        Console.WriteLine(rutaVideo);

    }
    else if (codFilai.StartsWith("v"))
    {
        ...
    }
...
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Este es el resultado devuelto por la consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen, en cada uno de los registros me dice que "el video **no** existe" y que la "portada **no** existe", pero en esas rutas **sí** existen esos ficheros, como se puede ver en la siguiente imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También intenté añadirle la ruta actual a la cadena de `rutaVideo` y `rutaPortada` de esta forma:

```
....
String rutaActual = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
...

if (codFilai.StartsWith("c"))
    {


        rutaVideo=rutaActual+"audiovisuales\\concierto\\"+codFilai+".flv'";
        rutaPortada=rutaActual+"audiovisuales\\concierto\\"+codFilai+".jpg'";
        Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(rutaVideo) ? "Video existe!" : "Video no existe.");
        Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(rutaPortada) ? "Portada existe!" : "Portada no existe.");
        Console.WriteLine(Directory.Exists("audiovisuales\\concierto\\") ? "Directorio existe!" : "Directorio no existe.");
        Console.WriteLine(rutaVideo);
...
```

Y sigo obteniendo el mismo resultado.

Si la ruta está correcta y los nombres de los ficheros también, entonces dónde me estoy equivocando para que no me encuentre los ficheros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has intentado quitar el `" ' "` en estas dos lineas?

```
rutaVideo=rutaActual+"audiovisuales\\concierto\\"+codFilai+".flv'";
rutaPortada=rutaActual+"audiovisuales\\concierto\\"+codFilai+".jpg'";
```

Es decir:

```
rutaVideo=rutaActual+"audiovisuales\\concierto\\"+codFilai+".flv";
rutaPortada=rutaActual+"audiovisuales\\concierto\\"+codFilai+".jpg";
```

Comment: Cierto, eso mismo era. No se como se me fue ese caracter y por mas que revisaba el codigo no lo veía. Muchas gracias :)